# How can Stack Overflow be successfully and effectively used for job search?

Tags: discussion

How can Stack Overflow be used successfully for job search?

By job search I mean not only "searching" for jobs, but actually getting those which not only pays well, but are also in line with your career goals and about technologies for which you are passionate.

We developers all want to work with technologies we like and love to grow old with them. How can Stack Overflow be effectively used to look for jobs which will complete you as a developer?

Comment: Are you looking for something more than "search for job, apply for job, get job"? If so please expand your question.

Comment: @TZHX Edited my Question, according to your suggestion!

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean. Are you aware of the "Jobs" tab on Stack Overflow? It allows you to specify technologies you hate or are passionate about, and tries to match you with jobs accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things Stack Overflow careers is:

1. A job board

Things Stack overflow careers is not:

1. A personal assistant dedicated to your career development;
2. A tutor in the process of looking for work;
3. Something that magically makes recruiters (who most will tell you are in the same league as lawyers and estate agents) honest.

If you want to find a job which will "complete" you, you need to decide for yourself what is missing in your career. This is usually going to be very personal to you. Do you want:

- more money?
- access to training?
- support for going through industry certifications (ccna, mcse, chartered status, etc.)?
- flashy company car?
- more time with your family?
- coworkers you can have a laugh with?
- coworkers who act professionally?
- managerial responsibility?

You need to decide what you want, look for jobs that claim to offer it, and then make a gut feeling when offered a job whether or not they're bullshitting you. Stack Overflow careers, being just a job board, can't really help with what you want.

Answer (score 3):

> "How can Stack Overflow be effectively used to look for jobs which will complete you as a developer?"

There's no such thing as a complete developer (except in the sense of deciding you've had enough and quitting).

But if you're looking for a job that lets you "expand" rather than "shrink", then find companies where you can tell who the employees are.  If you look at their page and can't find any of its developers' names--or if you can find them but the developers can never seem to talk about what they're working on (or aren't showing up at any conferences)...odds are you'll be invisible too.

My main advice would be to fight that invisibility factor.  You can do it independently of anything you're working on--through your personal projects or blog--but if your job is on your team in this, that's ideal.